# Regular Expression Validator does not validate until after the form is submitted

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Email" runat="server" ValidationGroup="register" Placeholder="Email" Width="250px" CausesValidation="true" required="true" MaxLength="200"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revEmailAddress" runat="server" SetFocusOnError="true" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="Email" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" ValidationGroup="register" ForeColor="Red">Please enter a valid email address.</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

If I test the above code in visual studio the validator works perfectly, but once I publish the project the validation only occurs after I submit my form which is useless. Why won't the validation work after publishing?

Comment: Try explicitly setting EnableClientScript to true on the control. It should be true by default though. Also are you using the same browser? Could be javascript is disabled on the servers browser if you are checking form there?

Comment: @Aaron , I am using the same browser and setting EnableClientScript to true had no affect.